# Синхронность for в js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет. Есть задача - реализовать синхронный вызов файла через `childProcess.execFile()`. Вариант `childProcess.execFileSync()` не подходит, поскольку не имеет коллбека, а мне это очень важно. Каким образом в данном коде можно сделать цикл `for (i = 0; i < sites.lenght; i++)` синхронным? Проблема в том, что при запуске всего скрипта, виснет комп из-за 3500 асинхронных процессов через `execFile()`

```
   var  express             = require("express"),
        request             = require('request'),
        bodyParser          = require("body-parser"),
        fs                  = require("fs"),
        colors              = require('colors/safe'),
        phantomjs           = require('phantomjs'),
        childProcess        = require('child_process'),     
        path                = require('path');

const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

var binPath = phantomjs.path;
var childArgs;
var sites = [];
fs.readFile('sites.txt', { encoding : 'utf8' },
    (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        data.split('\n').forEach(line => {
            sites.push(line.slice(0,-1));
    });     

    for (i = 0; i < sites.lenght; i++) {


        var site = 'http://' + sites[i] + "/";


        var childArgs = [
            path.join(__dirname, 'prod.js'),
            site
        ];      
        childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {   
            console.log(stdout);
            const dom = new JSDOM(stdout);
            var links = dom.window.document.links;
            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                if(links[i].href.indexOf('vk.com') + 1) {
                    var str = "\r\n"+site+':'+links[i].href;
                    fs.appendFile('success.txt', str, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {                    
                            console.log(str);                                                       
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }   
});
```

Comment: _"Вариант childProcess.execFileSync() не подходит, поскольку не имеет коллбека, а мне это очень важно."_ - нет.

Comment: Коллбэк выполняется в момент завершения асинхронной операции, которой в синхронном выполнении просто нет. Вы можете просто дальше по коду эту функцию вызвать ровно с тем же эффектом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дак а в чем проблема использовать собственно callback? Вам нужно не использовать цикл for, а сделать следующее
Занести `childProcess.execFile` в функцию, которая будет принимать помимо значений, передаваемых в `childProcess.execFile` еще и `currentPostition`, `totalPositions` а в коллбэке проверять - если текущая позиция (`currentPosition`) равна количеству позиций (`totalPositions`) - то просто вернуть `true`, иначе увеличить текущую позицию на единицу и выполнить эту функцию уже для следующего файла. Т.е. получится рекурсия - пока не исполнится последний файл. Надеюсь, алгоритм понятен.

Ну а если вам коллбэк нужен только после того как исполнятся все файлы - то заносите это в условие "если текущая позиция равна количеству позиций"

Comment: Сделал так, как Вы сказали. Получаю ошибку `spawn ENOMEM` от `childProcess`

Comment: Возможно, у вас много файлов и в итоге отъедается куча памяти. Пробовали на скольки файлах и какого размера?

Comment: файлов немного, проблема в 3.5к итераций. На данный момент, пробовал на всех 3.5к

Comment: Попробуйте на десятке-двух итераций, просто чтоб знать работает ли. И можно увидеть что получилось?

Comment: К тому же, если сами файлы очень большие - то использовать exec не рекомендуется, т.к. она использует буфер, изначально равный 200к (можно увеличить, но это делать не рекомендуют). Для больших файлов применяется spawn

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, можно было бы воспользоваться следующим решением: [Как последовательно вызвать асинхронную функцию с коллбеками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708781/178988).

Но вообще-то в твоём случае правильнее использовать синхронный вариант функции и вызывать желаемый callback самостоятельно в try-catch.