# Как последовательно вызвать асинхронную функцию с коллбеками?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-faq

Есть массив, для каждого элемента которого следует вызвать асинхронную функцию, возвращающую значение через коллбэк.

Однако, требуется вызвать их последовательно, а именно, следующий вызов надо совершать только тогда, когда завершилась обработка предыдущего.

Вот так получается одновременно:

```js
function doSmth(x, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, Math.random() * 100 | 0, null, x);
}

var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

for (var x of data) {
  doSmth(x, function (err, res) {
    console.log(err || res);
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Надо делать вызов внутри коллбека. Для этого придётся переписать цикл на рекурсию ([ну или не совсем рекурсию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/619130/178988)):

```js
function doSmth(x, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, Math.random() * 100 | 0, null, x);
}

var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

(function go(i) { // <================== рекурсивная функция вместо цикла
  if (i >= data.length) {
    return; // <======================== выход, когда массив закончился
  }
  
  doSmth(data[i], function (err, res) {
    console.log(err || res);
    
    go(i + 1); // <===================== рекурсивный вызов из коллбэка
  });
})(0);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

И остаётся ещё один момент - обычно нам бы надо узнать, когда завершилась обработка. Для этого функция go вместо `return` может вызвать другой коллбэк из вызывающей функции:

```js
function doSmth(x, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, Math.random() * 100 | 0, null, x);
}

function process(data, callback) {
  (function go(i) { // <================== рекурсивная функция вместо цикла
    if (i >= data.length) {
      return callback(null, null); // <=== return позволяет избежать рекурсивного вызова
    }

    doSmth(data[i], function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err, null); // <== прекращаем дальнейшую обработку
      }
    
      console.log(res);

      go(i + 1); // <===================== рекурсивный вызов из коллбэка
    });
  })(0);
}

var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

process(data, function (err, res) {
  console.log(err || "Готово!");
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: я уверен уже было несколько вопросов с последовательным выполнением асинхронных функций

Comment: @Grundy, помню [вот этот](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/178988), но он про другое, хотя и связан с этим.

Comment: А [вот этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536917/186999)?

Comment: @Grundy, во-первых, его ещё надо найти. Во-вторых, на faq он не тянет. Ну и наконец, я хотел описать именно выпрямление цикла в случае, когда функция с коллбеками уже есть и её трогать нельзя и не надо.

Answer (score 5):

В последних версиях языка есть механизмы, позволяющие писать более понятный код чем вариант с рекурсией.

Для начала, надо преобразовать функцию так, чтобы она возвращала обещание (Promise). Переписывать ее для этого не нужно: достаточно обернуть.

```
function doSmth1(x) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         doSmth(x, (err, result) => {
             if (err)
                 reject(err);
             else
                 resolve(result);
         });
     });
}
```

Также можно один раз написать функцию, которая будет оборачивать любую заданную (или взять ее из какой-нибудь библиотеки):

```
function promisify(f) {
    return function(...args) {
         return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             f.call(this, ...args, (err, result) => {
                 if (err)
                      reject(err);
                 else
                      resolve(result);
             });
         });
    }
}

var doSmth1 = promisify(doSmth);
```

Это позволяет использовать асинхронные функции из стандарта ES2017:

```
async function foo() {
    var doSmth1 = promisify(doSmth);
    for (var x of data) {
        console.log(await doSmth1(x));
    }
}
```

Если по какой-то причине нет желания выделять целую функцию под асинхронный код - нет проблем вызвать анонимную функцию на месте:

```
(async () => {
    var doSmth1 = promisify(doSmth);
    for (var x of data) {
        console.log(await doSmth1(x));
    }
})();
```

PS когда вы пишите свои асинхронные функции, имеет смысл делать их "двойного назначения" - одновременно принимающими callback и возвращающими Promise. Это не трудно, но способы написания таких функций выходят за рамки ответа.

Comment: Добавил бы сниппет в конец... А вообще, по-моему, это стоило отдельным вопросом с ответом делать.

Comment: @Qwertiy да нет, это именно что ответ на вопрос "как последовательно вызвать асинхронную функцию с коллбеками?" - обернуть в промизы и воспользоваться новыми средствами языка. Цель ответа - показать что новые средства языка прикладной код не усложняют - а упрощают, и как их использовать в легаси-окружении.