# вставка кода как в jQuery.html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

в jquery можно сделать так:

```js
$('#bla').html('hello<script>alert(1)<\/script>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='bla'></div>
```

при этом вставляется текст и запускается скрипт.

как сделать то же самое, только без jQuery?

пробую через innerHTML, но оно только добавляет html, но не выполняет код

Comment: связанный вопрос: [HTML.innerHTML vs Jquery.html() - Javascript execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584931/2881286)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При условии наличия только инлайн-скриптов на js так:

```js
var dest = document.getElementById('dest');
var html = 'hello<script>console.log(1)<\/script> world<script>console.log(2)<\/script>!';

dest.innerHTML = html;

for (var s of dest.querySelectorAll('script')) {
  (1,eval)(s.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div id='dest'></div>
```

Comment: а если не только инлайн скрипты?

Comment: Тогда надо их поштучно проверять на src, вызывать загрузку скриптов, ждать, пока они выполнятся и переходить к следующему.

Comment: а как их вызывать? те что с src

Comment: document.createElement('script') и так далее.

Comment: Можете написать полный код? А то сейчас ковыряю, никак не могу разобраться с тем чтобы ждать выполнения не инлайн-скриптов.

Comment: @Ивашка, https://habrahabr.ru/post/182310/ `var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  document.head.appendChild(script);` Подписаться на `script.onload`. Ну и собрать это воедино через https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/708782/178988 PS: Попозже напишу, если не забуду.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - добавляй js-код в фунцию и выполняй ее после добавления блока на страницу.

UPD:

Пример решения:

Если так важен именно инлайн скрипт, то переделаем его следующим образом. Оберене все его содержимое в одну функцию, которую будем вызывать.

```js
var inner = 'hello<script>function onready() { alert(1); }<\/script>';
document.getElementById('bla').innerHTML = inner;
onready();
```

```html
<div id="bla"></div>
```

Comment: То ли не ответ на вопрос, то ли ответ слишком непонятен

Comment: @andreymal привел пример того, что имел ввиду

Comment: перенес  код в сниппет, можно заметить, что твой пример не работает