# Почему функция возвращает результат, хотя она еще не закончила свою работу?

Tags: javascript, node.js

П.С. Модераторы только видят слово асинхронность, сразу лепят дубликат. Приходится переформулировать вопрос.

Создаю для MongoDb документ (карточка товара). В процессе выполнения функции, должна происходить запись нескольких фотографий этого товара. Вот здесь и возникла проблема - функция завершает свое выполнение раньше, чем происходит запись файлов. Даже один не успевает записаться). Ниже код, я его минимизировал:

```
function createGoods(dataGoods, callback) {
    var k = JSON.parse(dataGoods);
    var f = {};
    f.img =[];
    //этот цикл не успевает завершиться, прежде, чем произойдет возврат 
      функции
    for (let i=0; i<k.img.length; i++){
        createFile(data, pathWriteFile, nameFile, function(name){
            f.img.push(name);
        });
    }
    f.visible = true;
    f.path = h;
    .........

    return callback(f);

}
```

Модуль записи файла

```
function createFile(data, pathWriteFile, nameFile, callback){
    fs.writeFile(pathWriteFile, data, "base64",function(err){
        return callback(nameFile);
        })
}
```

Почему функция возвращает результат, хотя цикл еще продолжает перебираться и функция, по факту еще не закончила свою работу?

Comment: Потому что writeFile асинхронный и работает "в фоне"
 (условно говоря)

Comment: Я бы тоже дубликат влепил. Файлы и не начнут записываться до тех пор, пока ваш код не завершит работу, именно потому что асинхронность

Comment: @andreymal, Не, это не помогает. (writeFileSync)Только что попробовал. Я вот что подумал, скорее всего,  цикл все-таки завершается. Он просто запускает функцию создания файлов  и ничего не ждет. И  `callback` в данной ситуации бесмысленный

Comment: @andreymal, все отрабатывает. Файлы записываются как положено.  Только информация об этом отсутствует в итоговом документе.

Comment: А вот если writeFileSync не помогает, то это уже совсем другой вопрос, более интересный. Вы учитываете, что у него нет аргумента callback и ваш function(err) не вызовется, если вы просто поменяли имя функции?

Comment: Возможно, стоит почитать о том, как работает асинхронность в JS, например, [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/company/wrike/blog/302896/).

Comment: И еще: [Как последовательно вызвать асинхронную функцию с коллбеками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708781/178779)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, последняя ссылка, прям то, что нужно. Пошел разбираться. Спасибо.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, поменяйте, пожалуйста, основной вопрос, дубликатом которого, является мой. На вот этот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708781/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8 . Здесь намного понятнее все описано, да и подходит под мою ситуацию лучше