# Ошибка в цикле for node.js

Tags: node.js, циклы, for

Почему после запуска такого цикла - в консоле выдает: -1? Хотя должен идти отсчет каждую секунду на -1. Нужно использовать именно цикл for, никаких других!

```js
for (var start = 993; start > 0; start = start - 7) {
    setTimeout(function () {console.log(start)}, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: `-1` ? Вы не ошиблись?

Comment: @Дмытрык, нажмите на "Выполнить код" и посмотрите

Comment: `Хотя должен идти отсчет каждую секунду на -1` А не `-7` ?. А по сути вопроса, консоль начинает вывод переменной `start` - в тот момент, когда она равна `-1`

Comment: @Дмытрык, смотрите, если я заменю "setTimeout(() => console.log(start), 1000)" - на "console.log(start)" - в консоль будет выводится без задержки отсчет по -7. Но мне нужна задержка в одну секунду. И не должно там каждую секунду выводить по -1. Вы где-то ошиблись.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как последовательно вызвать асинхронную функцию с коллбеками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708781/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: @Дмытрык вообще ни разу не похожи эти вопросы... Вы можете нормальный ответ дать, а не писать черт знает что?

Comment: Там не вопрос важен, а ответы. Еще раз: Ваш цикл обрабатывается быстрее, чем запускается 1-я функция. На момент запуска функции, переменная уже равна -1. Вот ее и выводит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замени `var` на `let` и будет как ты хочешь

```js
for (let start = 993; start > 0; start = start - 7) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(start)
  }, 1000);
}
```