# Почему запрос возвращает пустой массив из MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

[image: Screen!]Всем привет. Изучаю стек MEAN. Разрабатываю приложение которое должно выдавать список мест, на оновании геолокации. есть база данных

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5abde0cb909b5ead83b99c51"),
        "name" : "Starcups",
        "address" : "Proletarskiy bld 3",
        "facilities" : [
                "Hot cheeks",
                "Food"
        ],
        "coords" : [
                37.581383,
                55.605522
        ],
        "openingTimes" : [
                {
                        "days" : "Monday - Friday",
                        "opening" : "7:00am",
                        "closing" : "7:00pm",
                        "closed" : false
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Saturday",
                        "opening" : "8:00am",
                        "closing" : "5:00pm",
                        "closed" : "false"
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Sunday",
                        "closed" : true
                }
        ],
        "reviews" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5abf70298abf321be4d2e5e6"),
                        "author" : "Peter",
                        "rating" : 5,
                        "reviewText" : "Nice place! I get it!",
                        "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-03-31T11:25:29.660Z")
                }
        ],
        "rating" : 5
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5abde0eb909b5ead83b99c52"),
        "name" : "Sberbank",
        "address" : "Proletarsky blb 6",
        "facilities" : [
                "Coffee",
                "Food",
                "Wifi"
        ],
        "coords" : [
                37.582592,
                55.605516
        ],
        "openingTimes" : [
                {
                        "days" : "Monday - Friday",
                        "opening" : "7:00am",
                        "closing" : "7:00pm",
                        "closed" : false
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Saturday",
                        "opening" : "8:00am",
                        "closing" : "5:00pm",
                        "closed" : false
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Sunday",
                        "closed" : true
                }
        ],
        "reviews" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5ac0c73729cf390bb8f3276e"),
                        "author" : "Kolya",
                        "rating" : 4,
                        "reviewText" : "Not bad.",
                        "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-04-01T11:49:11.047Z")
                }
        ],
        "rating" : 4
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ac110d1117138f6e5a919d2"),
        "name" : "Park",
        "address" : "Proletarsky blb 6",
        "facilities" : [
                "Coffee",
                "Food",
                "Wifi"
        ],
        "coords" : [
                37.67398,
                55.598169
        ],
        "openingTimes" : [
                {
                        "days" : "Monday - Friday",
                        "opening" : "7:00am",
                        "closing" : "7:00pm",
                        "closed" : false
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Saturday",
                        "opening" : "8:00am",
                        "closing" : "5:00pm",
                        "closed" : false
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Sunday",
                        "closed" : true
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ac11135117138f6e5a919d3"),
        "name" : "Norm mesto",
        "address" : "Proletarskiy bld 3",
        "facilities" : [
                "Hot cheeks",
                "Food"
        ],
        "coords" : [
                37.673712,
                55.599026
        ],
        "openingTimes" : [
                {
                        "days" : "Monday - Friday",
                        "opening" : "7:00am",
                        "closing" : "7:00pm",
                        "closed" : false
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Saturday",
                        "opening" : "8:00am",
                        "closing" : "5:00pm",
                        "closed" : "false"
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Sunday",
                        "closed" : true
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ac11179117138f6e5a919d4"),
        "name" : "mesto",
        "address" : "Proletarskiy bld 3",
        "facilities" : [
                "Hot cheeks",
                "Food"
        ],
        "coords" : [
                37.672151,
                55.59847
        ],
        "openingTimes" : [
                {
                        "days" : "Monday - Friday",
                        "opening" : "7:00am",
                        "closing" : "7:00pm",
                        "closed" : false
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Saturday",
                        "opening" : "8:00am",
                        "closing" : "5:00pm",
                        "closed" : "false"
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Sunday",
                        "closed" : true
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ac111c0117138f6e5a919d5"),
        "name" : "Biryliovo",
        "address" : "Proletarskiy bld 3",
        "facilities" : [
                "Hot cheeks",
                "Food"
        ],
        "coords" : [
                37.672821,
                55.597455
        ],
        "openingTimes" : [
                {
                        "days" : "Monday - Friday",
                        "opening" : "7:00am",
                        "closing" : "7:00pm",
                        "closed" : false
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Saturday",
                        "opening" : "8:00am",
                        "closing" : "5:00pm",
                        "closed" : "false"
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Sunday",
                        "closed" : true
                }
        ]
}
```

есть контроллер

```
module.exports.locationsListByDistance = function(req, res) {
  var lng = parseFloat(req.query.lng);
  var lat = parseFloat(req.query.lat);
  var maxDistance = parseFloat(req.query.maxDistance);
  if ((!lng && lng!==0) || (!lat && lat!==0) || ! maxDistance) {
    console.log('locationsListByDistance missing params');
    sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
      "message": "lng, lat and maxDistance query parameters are all required"
    });
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('locationsListByDistance running...');
    Loc.aggregate(
      [{
        $geoNear: {
          near: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [lng, lat]
            },
          spherical: true,
          distanceField: 'dist',
          maxDistance: maxDistance
        }
      }],
      function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
          sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
        } else {
          locations = buildLocationList(req, res, results);
          sendJSONresponse(res, 200, locations);
        }
      }
    )
  };
};

var buildLocationList = function(req, res, results, stats) {
  var locations = [];
  results.forEach(function(doc) {
    locations.push({
      distance: doc.dis,
      name: doc.obj.name,
      address: doc.obj.address,
      rating: doc.obj.rating,
      facilities: doc.obj.facilities,
      _id: doc.obj._id
    });
  });
  return locations;
};
```

есть схема

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: {type: String, required: true},
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    reviewText: {type: String, required: true},
    createdOn: {
        type: Date,
        "default": Date.now
    }
});

var openingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    days: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    opening: String,
    closing: String,
    closed: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    }
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: String,
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        "default": 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    facilities: [String],
    // Always store coordinates longitude, latitude order.
    coords: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
    },
    openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
    reviews: [reviewSchema]
});

mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

и есть модуль angular

```
angular.module('loc8rApp', []);

var _isNumeric = function (n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
};

var formatDistance = function () {
  return function (distance) {
   var numDistance, unit;
  if (distance && _isNumeric(distance)) {
    if (distance > 1) {
      numDistance = parseFloat(distance).toFixed(1);
      unit = 'km';
    } else {
      numDistance = parseInt(distance * 1000,10);
      unit = 'm';
    }
    return numDistance + unit;
  } else {
    return "?";
  }
};
};

var ratingStars = function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            thisRating : '=rating'
        },
        templateUrl : '/angular/rating-stars.html'
    };
};
var geolocation = function () {
  var getPosition = function (cbSuccess, cbError, cbNoGeo) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(cbSuccess, cbError);
    }
    else {
      cbNoGeo();
    }
  };
  return {
    getPosition : getPosition
  };
};

var locationListCtrl = function ($scope, loc8rData, geolocation) {
  $scope.message = "Checking your location";

  $scope.getData = function (position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude,
        lng = position.coords.longitude;
    $scope.message = "Searching for nearby places";
    loc8rData.locationByCoords(lat, lng)
      .then(function successCallback(data) {
        $scope.message = data.length > 0 ? "" : "No locations found nearby";
        $scope.data = { locations: data };
      });
      function errorCallback(e) {
        $scope.message = "Sorry, something's gone wrong, please try again later";
      };
  };

  $scope.showError = function (error) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.message = error.message;
    });
  };

  $scope.noGeo = function () {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.message = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    });
  };

  geolocation.getPosition($scope.getData,$scope.showError,$scope.noGeo);
};

var loc8rData = function ($http) {
  var locationByCoords = function (lat, lng) {
    return $http.get('/api/locations?lng=' + lng + '&lat=' + lat + '&maxDistance=10');
  };
  return {
    locationByCoords : locationByCoords
  };

};

angular
 .module('loc8rApp', [])
 .controller('locationListCtrl', locationListCtrl)
 .filter('formatDistance', formatDistance)
 .directive('ratingStars', ratingStars)
 .service('loc8rData', loc8rData)
 .service('geolocation', geolocation);
```

Проблема в том что запрос типа /api/locations?lng=37.6736693&lat=55.5983054&maxDistance=10  возвращает пустой массив []

Если я задаю запрос непосредственно в mongodb он выдает мне нормальный список мест радиусе моей геолокации. Помогите кто может. Уже нет сил вторую неделю пытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: Если проблема в самом запросе, то его и нужно было выкладывать. Где он , кстати?

Comment: В последнем файле.          var loc8rData = function ($http) {
  var locationByCoords = function (lat, lng) {
    return $http.get('/api/locations?lng=' + lng + '&lat=' + lat + '&maxDistance=10');
  };
  return {
    locationByCoords : locationByCoords
  };

Comment: Ваш вопрос звучит: " Почему запрос возвращает пустой массив из MongoDB?" Где этот запрос в БД?

Comment: Сам запрос в котроллере - locationsListByDistance. Но я подозреваю что, проблема в контроллере - buildLocationList который делает выборку из locationsListByDistance и должен отправлять данные в виде массива. Он отправляет его пустым!

Comment: если я захожу непосредственно в mongodb и делаю следующий запрос 'db.locations.aggregate(
[
    {
        '$geoNear': {
            'near': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [ 37.5819616, 55.605287]
            },
            'spherical': true, 
            'distanceField': 'dist',
            'maxDistance': 5000         
        }
    }
]);'     монго выдает мне список в радиусе 5км. я просто запутался

Comment: Может быть такое, что ответ уходит раньше, чем отработает функция? Вы проверяли это?

Comment: Если честно не думал об этом. как это можно проверить?

Comment: Перед отправкой ответа выведите в консоль его.  И в самой функции, перед return

Comment: сделал как Вы сказали(надеюсь что правильно) и кажется действительно, массив преждевременно уходит пустым.На прикрепленном скрине видно что массив уходит пустым. Или я ничего не понимаю((  Если подскажите как мне решить эту проблему я буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, мне ситуация видится так. В Вашем контролере наблюдаются 2 проблемы. Одна уже себя проявила, вторая - потенциальная.

1) Функция `buildLocationList` возвращает результат раньше, чем отработает цикл внутри нее. Есть только одно, известное мне, решение этой проблемы - рекурсия. 
[Как последовательно вызвать асинхронную функцию с коллбеками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708781/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) - в ответе @Qwertiy есть пример рекурсии.

2) Вторая проблема, которая, скорее всего возникнет - строка `sendJSONresponse(res, 200, locations)` отработает раньше, чем отработает функция `buildLocationList`. В связи с этим, будет либо ошибка, либо опять возвращать пустой массив (зависит другого кода, который не вошел в пример). Решение этой проблемы - запускать `sendJSONresponse` в коллбэке функции `buildLocationList`, либо бороться с асинхронностью другими способами из арсенала ES6

Comment: Спасибо за участие! Буду делать по Вашей рекоммендации! Вы мне очень помогли! К сожалению не могу пока отметить ответ как полезный, т.к. еще не заработал репутацию.

Comment: Главное, чтобы рекомендации помогли. Кроме того, что отметить ответ как "полезный", задающий вопрос может поставить галочку "что ответ ему помог".