# Выполнение синхронной функции после асинхронной

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, асинхронность, promise

Появилась необходимость сделать так, чтобы сразу после выполнения асинхронной функции началось выполнение синхронной, и только в таком порядке. Пробовал варианты с `Promise` и `async/await`, но к правильному решению так и не пришел.

Необходимо после выполнения функции `getAllItems` выполнить `doAfter`.

```
function getPokemon(id) {
  fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`)
    .then(function (response) {
      response.json()
        .then(function (pokemon) {
          createSliderItem(id, pokemon);
        });
    });
}

async function getAllItems() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    getPokemon(i);
  }    
}

doAfter() {
  // ....
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708781/178988 - оно?

Comment: Для чего сообществу программистов знать о твоих потребностях, какую пользу ему принесет твой рассказ вместо вопроса?