# Как ожидать завершения выполнения асинхронного метода?

Tags: node.js, async-await

Как мне дождаться выполнения асинхронного метода?

```js
const array = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

async function load(id) {
    await setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Успешная загрузка #"+id)
    }, Math.random() * 1000 | 0)
}

array.forEach((id, i) => {
    console.log("Загрузка #"+id)
    load(id)
})
```

В результате этого куска кода, сначала выполняется цикл а затем выполняются функции в нем... Как мне сделать так, что бы следуюший цикл выполнялся только после выполнения предыдущего..?
Консоль:

```
Загрузка #1 
Загрузка #2
Загрузка #3 
Загрузка #4
Успешная загрузка #1 
Успешная загрузка #3 
Успешная загрузка #2 
Успешная загрузка #4
```

А нужно:

```
Загрузка #1 
Успешная загрузка #1 
Загрузка #2
Успешная загрузка #2
Загрузка #3 
Успешная загрузка #3 
Загрузка #4
Успешная загрузка #4
```

Comment: Или всё-таки не дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708781/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy , тот вариант мне не помог, так что я не думаю что это дубликат. Да и в ноде появились новые функции связанные с асинхронными методами...

Comment: Ok, поверю. Но по вопросу не понятно, что ты хочешь.

Comment: Не знаю как обьяснить...

Comment: @Qwertiy Так понятнее?

Comment: Предложил альтернативный вариант. В принципе, то, что ты хочешь, тоже можно сделать, но там сложнее. Думаю, вариант с массивом должен подойти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то типа такого

```js
const array = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ];

~async function testFN(array, callback) {
 for (let id = 0; id < array.length; id++) {
  console.log("Загрузка #"+id);
  await callback(array[id], id, array);
 }
}(array, load);

function load(id) {
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Успешная загрузка #" + id);
  resolve(id);
 }, Math.random() * 1000 | 0));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант помог мне.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно подойдёт такой вариант:

```js
const array = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

function load(id) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Успешная загрузка #" + id)
    resolve(id)
  }, Math.random() * 1000 | 0))
}

~async function main() {
  var res = await Promise.all(array.map((id, i) => {
    console.log("Загрузка #" + id)
    return load(id)
  }))
  
  console.log(res) // Обрабатываем массив результатов
}()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не решает вопрос