# Как осуществить передачу нескольких GET запросов через Promise.all с помощью node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Всем привет. Скажу сразу, только недавно окунулся в мир JS и NodeJs. 
Задача следующая, мне нужно сделать неопределенное количество GET-запросов на страницы отличающиеся лишь инкрементированным индексом (+1). НЕ могу понять, как с помощью Promise.all передать результаты запросов в массив и прекратить передачу при статусе 500, 404.
Вот код, который есть сейчас у меня:

```
const https = require('https');

var arrayOfHTML = [];
let time = new Date().getTime();
var str = '';
callback = function(response) {
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        let a = JSON.parse((str)); //преобразовать строку в JSON
        arrayOfHTML[i] = a[0].content.trim();//добавить свойство контент в массив
        //На этом этапе массив полон, но при вызове за пределами ИМЕННО
        //ЭТОЙ ФУНКЦИИ, то массив пустой
    });
};
let i=0;
while (i < 45){
    https.request(`https://www.somesite.com/Example?page=${i}&pageAction=getPage&_=${time}`, callback).end();
    i++;
}
```

Он не до конца подходит так как запись в массив не производиться корректно и отправка запросов циклом не самая лучшая идея. 
Помогите пожалуйста переделать под промисы.
Коротко: мне нужно отправлять запросы на отличающиеся адреса до тех пор, пока statusCode = 200, при ином результате - вернуть ответы удачных запросов в виде массива.

Comment: Promise.all вам в этом не поможет. Читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708781/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как последовательно вызвать асинхронную функцию с коллбеками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708781/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko там используется определенный массив, а мне нужно делать неопределенное количество запросов. один раз 20, другой 45, в третий 82 и тд. 
Простите, если не увидел там ответа на свой вопрос, но мне кажется, что промисами с перехватом статуса 404 и 500 будет правильнее.
Хотя, возможно я и ошибаюсь

Comment: Вместо определенного массива вы можете использовать циклы - *один раз 20, другой 45, в третий 82 и тд.*. Промисы ничем не отличаются от колбеков по своему функционалу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

45 одновременных запросов это - бессмысленная нагрузка и на источник данных, и на ваш сервер.

Я видел в вашем предыдущем вопросе, что вы загружаете данные с сайта букмекерской конторы "Марафон". Решим задачу на с помощью цепочки промисов:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

loadMarathonbet(45)
  .then((marathonbetFootballPages) => {
    console.log(marathonbetFootballPages);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));


function loadMarathonbet(depth) {
    return loadMarathonbetPage(1, depth);
}

function loadMarathonbetPage(pageNumber = 1, depth = null, acc = []) {
    if (depth && depth < pageNumber) {
        return Promise.resolve(acc);
    }
    console.log(pageNumber);
    return axios.get('https://www.marathonbet.ru/su/popular/Football',
        {
            params: {page: pageNumber, pageAction: 'getPage', _: new Date().valueOf()},
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
        }
    )
    .then(({ data }) => {
        if (data) {
            const [pageContent, ...properties] = data;
            const hasNextPage = (properties.find((x) => x && x.prop === 'hasNextPage') || {}).val === true;
            if (pageContent) {
                acc.push({pageNumber, pageContent: pageContent.content});
            }
            if (hasNextPage) {
                return loadMarathonbetPage(pageNumber + 1, depth, acc);
            }
        }
        return acc;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return acc;
    });
}
```

Comment: Очень хороший вариант, но как долго будет обрабатываться запрос, если параллельно мне нужно зайти на страницу каждого условного матча и спарсить некоторые данные еще и там? При этом добавляя и редактируя данные в бд. Подойдет ли для многопотока цепочка промисов?

Answer (score 1):

оберните запрос в промис (а лучше не колупайтесь с этим и сразу используйте библиотеку axios которая сразу возвращает промис)

```
const myAsyncRequest = function(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const callback = function(response) {
      if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return reject(response.statusMessage);
      }

      let str = '';

      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
          str += chunk;
      });
      response.on('end', function () {
        let a = JSON.parse((str)); //преобразовать строку в JSON

        return resolve(a);
      });
    };

    const req = https.request(url, callback);

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      return reject(err);
    });

    req.end();

  });
}
```

теперь можете создать массив промисов:

```
const promiseArr = [];

while (i < 45){
  promiseArr.push(
    myAsyncRequest(someBasicUrl + i)
  );
  i++;
}

Promise.all(promiseArr)
  .then(arrOfResults => {arrOfResults.forEach( do something... )})
  .catch(err => {console.error('wait! oh shh...')})
```

Comment: лучше было посоветовать сделать цепочку промисов, а не отсылать на сервер 45 запросов одновременно

Comment: @nörbörnën Мне, как новичку было бы интересно изучить и ваш вариант, может вы можете его показать?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Это почти то, что нужно, но если хотя бы 1 запрос вернет статус 500, то будет вывод только ошибки, а мне нужен массив с данными с 200 кодом.
Возможно ли это вообще при помощи промисов? Если нет, то что я могу использовать?

Comment: @Glechik если вам больше подходит такое поведение, используйте Promise.allSettled вместо Promise.all (описание - https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-api#promise-allsettled), а потом массив ответов надо будет фильтрануть. еще вариант в Promise.all вместо reject использовать resolve(null) и выполнение не упадет с ошибкой. а массив потом опять же фильтрануть.

Comment: @Glechik  в случае с возвращением null на неудачу массив ответов можно отфильтровать очень коротко: arrOfResults.filter(item => Boolean(item))

Comment: @nörbörnën лучше для каких целей? параллельная отправка отработает быстрее. но есть конечно нюансы. например некоторые сервисы могут заблокировать твой ip при слишком обращении к api. у обоих подходов есть плюсы и минусы

Comment: @Glechik а еще рекомендую вместо нативного промиса использовать библиотеку bluebird. 1) работает быстрее; 2) она имеет все те же методы, но еще кучу своих для разных вариантов обработки результатов. почитайте доку, возможно вам что-то подойдет. если в index.js (или как там в вашем проекте точка входа называется) первой строчкой написать global.Promise = require("bluebird"); то при каждом вызове промиса будет на самом деле вызываться блюберд а не нативный вариант

Comment: @Glechik вечером напишу свой вариант на цепочке

Answer (score 1):

для сравнения покажу как уменьшится код при использовании аксиос.

```
const axios = require("axios");

const promiseArr = [];

while (i < 45){
  promiseArr.push(
    axios.get(someBasicUrl + i)
      .then(res => res.data) // кстати json тут уже распарсили и мы сразу возвращаем джаваскриптовый объект
      .catch(err => { console.error(err); return null; }); // раз уж мы не хотим ронять процесс при неудаче одного из запросов
  );
  i++;
}

Promise.all(promiseArr)
  .then(results => results.filter(item => Boolean(item)))
  .then(filteredResults => do something...)
  .catch(err => you never know what will happen...);
```

т.е. весь первый сниппет кода из предыдущего ответа сократился до одной строчки

Comment: Спасибо большое