# Как зацыклить уже имеющийся цикл в JavaScript'e

Tags: javascript

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("класс-элемента");
var page = document.getElementByClassName("класс кнопки след.страницы");
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
list[i].click();

}
```

Дали задание,имеется сайт с 1000+ страницами и на каждой из странице есть элемент который нужно нажать.
Я сделал цикл который ищет и нажимает все элементы с страницы на которой я сижу,но нужно чтобы после завершения цикла он перешел на след.страницу и начал цикл заново и так до тех пор пока элемент "класс кнопки след.страницы" не исчезнет.
Пробовал двумя циклами но не выходит,буду очень благодарен за любую подсказку

Comment: Поместить его в цикл, который перебирает вашу 1000 страниц.

Comment: Никак. При переходе на другую страницу скрипты уже не выполняются. Хотя, если у тебя SPA, то загрузка страниц всё равно асинхронная и твой код должен её дожидаться. Можно использовать тамауты или какой-нибудь mutation observer, а сам цикл - вот так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708781/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy мб можно инкрементить згачения атрибута в урл при переходе? и таким образом передавать данные между страницами. или я не правильно понял проблему?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ты в консоли браузера запускаешь скрипт. Когда ты перейдёшь на другую страницу, он там уже выполняться не будет. Должно быть либо расширение, либо что-то внешние типа селениума, но не скрипт из консоли. Скрипт из консоли может попытаться запросить все страницы ajax'ом и распрасить - но это по ситуации.

Comment: произвольный скрипт подключить ко всем страницам можно? или может быть есть такой скрипт и можно его поменять?

Comment: Тут, наверное, нужно уточнение. Как и где вы запускаете код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из простого, рекурсией, мне кажется, удобней всего делать что-то подобное.
Не очень понятно, вы абстрактную функцию рассматриваете или что-то реальное делаете. 
Если не углубляться, то что-то такое должно получиться.

```js
//объявляем функцию кликер, которая принимает url страницы, где нужно нажать на элементы
function clicker(url) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("класс-элемента").forEach((item)=>{
        item.click();
    })//кликаем по элементам
    
    //в текущем варианте nextUrl будет просто ссылкой на элемент. Нужно получить именно url, на который ссылается этот элемент. Метод его получения зависит от реализации кнопки.
    let nextUrl = document.getElementByClassName("класс кнопки след.страницы")
  
    nextUrl && clicker(nextUrl); //если на странице был найден URL следующей страницы, то запускаем кликер и передаем ему URL следующей страницы
}
```