# как циклично сохранять файл json?

Tags: javascript, node.js

не судите строго, я начинающий програмист и изучаю пайтон. подскажите как код этой библиотеки https://www.npmjs.com/package/gamedig

```
    const Gamedig = require('gamedig');
Gamedig.query({
    type: 'minecraft',
    host: 'mc.example.com'
}).then((state) => {
    console.log(state);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Server is offline");
});
```

обернуть в цикл и сохранять в файл json чтобы использовать в дальнейшем в python

Comment: Признаюсь, до меня очень догло доходило, что вы хотите сделать

Answer (score 0):

```
const Gamedig = require('gamedig');

while (true) {
  await Gamedig.query({
    type: 'minecraft',
    host: 'mc.example.com'
  }).then((state) => {
    console.log(state);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Server is offline");
  });
}
```

PS: [Как последовательно вызвать асинхронную функцию с коллбеками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708781/178988)